# Use Firebase Database with MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an android application project which needs to retrieve/store data with the offline capability(which Firebase does the best) but my client needed that the data should be stored in MySQL for use in CRM application too.

So I wanted to ask is there a way to sync Firebase with MySQL? I'm currently used Firebase JS Library combined with PHP insert command which may cause a problem if there's no internet connection or SQL server is down.

Thanks!

Comment: Firebase is noSQL, which made it case by case to be implemented a "sync" job. Practical way (for me) is to create an app (like NodeJs) and listen to Firebase, and push it to MySQL whenever data changed

Comment: How to synchronize Firebase with mySQL has been asked a few times before, so I suggest you have a look at those: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+mysql. If you're having a hard time making a specific approach work, update your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it's by far the best way to increase the chances of getting a useful answer.